# Can I reprint obscure OGL rules in my campaign setting book?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ogl

I am presently writing a campaign setting for Pathfinder 1e, in which several rules from the adventure paths and third-party books are used.  For example, it uses rules for modern firearms, and city modifiers from a third party source.  All of them are already available for free on d20pfsrd.org.  But I want to sell this in a paper book, and would like to include the OGL rules in sidebars for small quotes, and in the main body text if they are too long for a two-page sidebar.  Am I allowed to do this, and if so, is there anything that I will need to do to make it compliant, other than list it in the references after the OGL itself?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Be sure to check out the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, you can

What you described is how OGL works (see [Pathfinder's OGL](http://legacy.aonprd.com/openGameLicense.html)), you must put a note with every other OGL reference that you use, usually at the end of the book. For more information, there is an [excellent podpast](http://knowdirectionpodcast.com/2016/11/private-sanctuary-297-bestow-insight-a-gnome-in-need-of-3pp/) from the guys at the *Know Direction* podcast talking about third-party publishing and OGL in general.

Publishers only refer to page number and book to save word count, otherwise, they would reprint the referenced rule. We could see this happening a lot on the earlier Pathfinder books, when they were still using 3.x and not their own system. Nowadays, we only see a stat block if that book is no longer in print or if there is any changes, correction or errata since that material was released.